# Creating a prefixed UISlider SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uislider

I've been trying to achieve such a result as below for sometime now i've been looking on cocaControls, but all controls is not working in swift, so my question is what is the easiest way and how can i create such a control as below where it snaps to points on a UISlider?

[image]

Comment: All these controls work in Swift. You have to configure your project correctly. See Apples Documentation: [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_77)

Comment: I know how to ad them into the bridge header, but they are 2 years old and not working proberly

Comment: So if u have an example of a project u know works, feel free to share